# How to return the mail html in cscart?

Tags: php, cs-cart

I am using the following function to send html mail in cscart.

```
  $value = fn_send_mail($user_data['email'], Registry::get('settings.Company.company_users_department'), 'addons/test/test_subj.tpl', 'addons/test/test_body.tpl');
```

If i print **$value** means it only return **1**. How do i return html in this function.

Comment: Which version of CS-Cart do you use? Because from 4.x the `fn_send_mail` function was replaced with the `Mailer::class`

Comment: I am using **CS-CART: version 2.2.1 PROFESSIONAL.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it :)

To display/retrun html template please use this following code.

```
$body = Registry::get('view_mail')->display($body, false);
print_r($body);
```

Comment: You are right, however you can check my detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

**Option 1**
You create your on mail sender function which will return the body, and you use this in your add-on. For example:

```
function custom_send_mail($to, $from, $subj, $body, $attachments = array(), $lang_code = CART_LANGUAGE, $reply_to = '', $is_html = true)
{
    fn_disable_translation_mode();
    $__from = array();
    $__to = array();

    fn_init_mailer();
    $mailer = & Registry::get('mailer');
    $languages = Registry::get('languages');
    Registry::get('view_mail')->setLanguage($lang_code);

    fn_set_hook('send_mail_pre', $mailer, $to, $from, $subj, $body, $attachments, $lang_code, $reply_to, $is_html);

    if (!empty($reply_to)) {
        $mailer->ClearReplyTos();
        $reply_to = fn_format_emails($reply_to);
        foreach ($reply_to as $rep_to) {
            $mailer->AddReplyTo($rep_to);
        }
    }

    if (!is_array($from)) {
        $__from['email'] = $from;
    } else {
        $__from = $from;
    }
    if (empty($__from['email'])) {
        $__from['email'] = Registry::get('settings.Company.company_site_administrator');
    }
    if (empty($__from['name'])) {
        $__from['name'] = Registry::get('settings.Company.company_name');
    }
    $mailer->SetFrom($__from['email'], $__from['name']);

    $mailer->IsHTML($is_html);
    $mailer->CharSet = CHARSET;
    $mailer->Subject = Registry::get('view_mail')->display($subj, false);
    $mailer->Subject = trim($mailer->Subject);
    $body = Registry::get('view_mail')->display($body, false);
    $mailer->Body = fn_attach_images($body, $mailer);

    if (!empty($attachments)) {
        foreach ($attachments as $name => $file) {
            $mailer->AddAttachment($file, $name);
        }
    }

    $__to = fn_format_emails($to);

    foreach ($__to as $v) {
        $mailer->ClearAddresses();
        $mailer->AddAddress($v, '');
        $result = $mailer->Send(); 
        if (!$result) {
            fn_set_notification('E', fn_get_lang_var('error'), fn_get_lang_var('error_message_not_sent') . ' ' . $mailer->ErrorInfo);
        }

        fn_set_hook('send_mail', $mailer);
    }
    return $body;
}
```

**Option 2**
You can connect to `send_mail_pre` hook via your add-on:

```
function fn_youraddonname_send_mail_pre($mailer, $to, $from, $subj, $body, $attachments, $lang_code, $reply_to, $is_html) {
    $rendered_body = Registry::get('view_mail')->display($body, false);
    // use your custom code, to do anything you want
    // this code will run everytime CS-Cart use the fn_send_mail function
}
```